# Benchmarking Lua

Tags: lua, benchmarking, microbenchmark

I want to benchmark some Lua without using external dependencies. I am currently using os.clock:

```
local function dummy() end
local start = os.clock()
for i=1,n do dummy() end -- loop/call overhead
local overhead = os.clock() - start
local start = os.clock()
for i=1,n do f() end
local time = os.clock() - start - overhead
```

Is this the right way to do benchmarking in Lua? Is there a better/more accurate way of doing benchmarking in Lua?

Comment: Off-topic because asking for off-site resources.  Anyway, I found [ProFi](https://gist.github.com/perky/2838755) and [luatrace](https://github.com/geoffleyland/luatrace).

Comment: @HenriMenke No I'm not.

Comment: Seems like a good way. You could also try the code from http://lua-users.org/wiki/ObjectBenchmarkTests

Answer (score 0):

See [Programming in Lua: Profiles](https://www.lua.org/pil/23.3.html). There, the creator of Lua himself (Roberto Ierusalimschy) cautions against reliance on Lua reflection (runtime access to internal Lua operations) for accurate profiling. Regarding timing profiles, he says:

> For a profile with timing, it is better to use the C interface: The overhead of a Lua call for each hook is too high and usually invalidates any measure.

Read the entire section for better context and a deeper look at Lua reflection.